# Checking if a TensorFlow install has XLA support

Tags: tensorflow

How can I check if a particular TensorFlow install was built with XLA support?  There is an option in `configure` to turn it off or on, but I don't see how to interrogate those options from Python.

Answer (score 1):

According to release notes for version [1.12.0](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.12.0)

> The pre-built binary for 1.12 is built with XLA support linked in by default.

You should be able to check for it inside 
`tensorflow.contrib.compiler`

or simply run:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.compiler import xla
```

if there is an `ImportError` you know xla isn't present.
The code referenced from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/tutorials/xla_compile).

Also for reference [XLA Overview](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/overview).